# Why is my Wi-fi Router speed test (sometimes) 4x faster than my laptop?

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router

I just got a new wireless router to take advantage of faster speeds (I'm on a 200 Mbps plan) and the router has a speed test function when you login to it. When I did so, it showed the following results (It uses Ookla to do the speed test):

[image: Router speed test results]

When I go to Speedtest.net (also uses Ookla for the speed test), I get the following results, approximately 1/4 of the router speeds (this is with no other devices actively browsing/using the network). The server connected to is the exact same for both tests.

[image: Laptop speed test results]

I expect some loss, but this seems like a huge difference.

I troubleshot with a couple other servers, and there were huge differences between some of the various servers. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Router/Laptop

- 234/137
- 234/231
- 234/36

The router is an Asus RT-AX86U. The laptop is an Inspiron 15G on Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What limits WiFi speed?](https://superuser.com/questions/363598/what-limits-wifi-speed)

Comment: Not really, I understand there are theoretical limits, but all the numbers are well below any limits of the router (it's a WiFi 6 router). And any other networks are extremely weak - 0 bars if they show up at all

Comment: Especially since I did get the one test to a server that showed very similar results to the router and the laptop

Comment: did you try to test with a Gigabit ethernet cable? For wifi speed to reach that value you'll need to make sure that the laptop connects to the router using 5GHz band and is close to the router

Comment: @phuclv - it's about 6' away on the 5GHz band. I have not tried with an ethernet cable yet